# remote control a download manager

Tags: remote, download-manager

I am pretty much a newbie, but I have set up an old pc to run Ubuntu as a file and print server in the home. So far everything is working great, but I want to be able to download files to the server, and control the download manager from another computer. Right now I just use `wget` in the terminal.

Is there a good program that does this remotely from a web interface or do I need to figure out how to access my terminal from another computer and continue to use `wget`?  And if so, are there good instructions on how to set that up?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aria2 is a terminal app but it has a webgui that you can use...if you can put your install of the webgui online then you could use that or if you are just working of a LAN then it could work that way too...though either way you will need to ssh or something into the computer to use these things.

There is not a simple solution right now but Aria2 does allow remote control through RPC. - http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: See eg: @ http://askubuntu.com/questions/270744/how-to-pause-a-running-aria-download  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/271175/how-to-enable-rpc-in-aria2c-download-manager