# Which download manager is capable of 'throttle' and 'pause & resume' a running instance of download from a script

Tags: scripts, downloads, remote-control, download-speed, download-manager

When downloading big files it necessary to pause the download many times. A big file can be downloaded by using `wget`. First start download, then kill `wget`, then resume download by `wget -c`.
I want to pause downloads too many times depending on events such as power failure, Network unavailability, etc... and want to automate it using a script. So pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is't an option. I know a process can be paused by `kill -STOP "$pid"` The pausing should not close the connection to the website, either it should wait for resume command or the bandwidth throttled to very low data useage.

[How to pause aria2 download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270744/how-to-pause-a-running-aria-download) is a partial solution but option *pause* is not supported in my `aria2` (1.8.0, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) and I can't upgrade `aria2` (From apt-get install or manually install ). This RPC option for `aria2` seems to works from *Ubuntu 11.10*.  So a portable version of `aria2` is also considerable.

**Looking for**
I'm looking for a download manager which is capable of **throttle bandwidth and pause/resume** all (or one ) the running instance of download upon execution of a `--throttle=10K`, `--pasue` switch or something like that, and resume it on a `--resume` switch (Or using other ways such as RPC).

I know `killall -9 $(pidof downloader)` should stop all downloads and can be resumed from the last point. But this only a bad choice for me as the number pause/resume is too high and the time to make connection to the server (where download file locate ) is a wastage of time and bandwidth.

`aria1` can do some job by `--stop` switch. But it's obsolete and solves it partially.

Comment: I use a windows app that allows you to throttle, pause and resume but not script. I use it under wine and found it useful, is that enough? Or is scripting a must have feature?

Comment: No. There are many DM capable of throttling. I need to throttle running instance from commandline.  Anyway name your DM and wine version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the question  (Thanks @rostislav-stribrny )

**JDownloader** is capable of *handling running instance of download* (throttle, pasue, resume, add etc) .

1. [Download](http://jdownloader.org/download/index) and install JDownloader  (Tested in v0.9)
2. Launch it
3. Install add-on **JD Remote Control** (Addons -> Addons manager-> JD remote)
4. Enable JD Remote Control (Addons -> (tick))
5. goto  `http://127.0.0.1:10025/help or http://localhost:10025/help`   ( IP:port  )

**Example**
To **throttle** all running download to 10K  `http://localhost:10025/action/set/download/limit/10`
From terminal `wget http://localhost:10025/action/set/download/limit/10`
To **pause** : `wget http://localhost:10025/action/pause`

Answer (score 4):

I'm using JDownloader. However, AFAIK running instance cannot be controlled by command line.

On the other hand, there are add-ons like:
- JD Scheduler or
- JD RemoteControl

which can do a great job.

See:
http://jdownloader.org/home/features
http://jdownloader.org/home/addons

(I guess that there will be more tools, maybe someone else will add another suggestion...)

Comment: Anyone some example please.

Comment: see http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/terminal/index

Comment: Even if your answer doesn't answer my question, it helped me to find the solution completely ( See my answer). So I award you the bounty

Comment: Running instances can be stop/resume without add-on

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend `Flareget`. it's free but you have to buy browser integration. here is it's features:

[Developer Webpage](http://flareget.com/)

[Download flareget](http://flareget.com/download/)

**Dynamic File Segmentation:** It uses a robust dynamic file segmentation algorithm to speed up the download. It supports up to 32 segments per download

**HTTP-Pipelining:** In addition to dynamic file segmentation, each segment is further accelerated up to six times

**Auto Segmentation:** When one segment ends, it starts another segment to help terminate another segment more fast

**Enhanced Browser Integration:** The only download manager for Linux which integrates with all the browsers to snatch away download url and start the download by itself. It does this magic without any addons

**Multi-protocol support:** It supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP protocols to let you download files from internet. It also supports Metalinks

**Intelligent file management:** It uses an intelligent file management system to automatically categorize your files based on their extensions. All the downloads are grouped in different folders as per their categories.

**Resume support:**  You can pause the downloads to download them later, you needn’t start from the beginning again. It also automatically retries when a segment or download fails

**Add or remove segments:** You can add or remove download segments dynamically without interrupting the download

**Clipboard Monitoring:** No need to copy paste your download links, it monitors your clipboard

**Limit downloads:**  You can limit the number of simultaneous downloads, when one download ends, another starts automatically

**Flash video download:** One click flash video download from most of the sites is supported for all the browsers.

**Smart Scheduler:** You can easily schedule flareGet to download files automatically. It allows you to start and pause downloading files at the set time.

**Batch Downloads:** You can simply import urls from a text file (each link in separate line) or an html file and download them all.

**Multi language support:** flareGet is being translated into many languages, currently English, Arabic, Italian, Chinese(Simplified), French, Czech, Bengali, Spanish and Brazilian Portuguese are available.

Comment: No CLI or RPC to use in script

Answer (score 1):

despite you seem to be looking for something very specific, and despite you solved it already, I would still like to recommend `uGet`, I've been using it sindce 12.04 (12.10 64 bits now) and I am very satisfied with the results!

Comment: No uGet ( `uget-get` ) didn't answer me as I need to throttle running instance of download from a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 10.04 get a copy of downloader for X

```
sudo apt-get install d4x
```

Will do everything you want :)

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/d4x/

Comment: It meets nothing.

Comment: OP wants a command line tool, which this definitely isn't.

Answer (score 0):

FlareGet 1.4-7 which is going to be released next week, supports all the features you need and even supports throttling of downloads. Here is the [changelog](http://flareget.com/changelog)

Here is the image, of the pre-release version showing speed limits:
[image]

Comment: No CLI or RPC to use in script

Answer (score 0):

Try Flareget, it has all and has its own PPA.

Answer (score -1):

I am user of fatrat. Thats the best download managee I have in Ubuntu . Fatrat low in size and best in performance.

```
sudo apt-get install fatrat
```

the above command will install the fatrat.