# downloaded a file without wget using browser can this be resumed it is broken download

Tags: downloads, wget, download-manager

I downloaded following file

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opsi/postdownload?source=dlp

file is 920 Mb approximately, I do not use any download manager it was a direct http download, after having approximately 600 Mb of download some how the download has broken, I have a file now opsi4.0.3-2-servervm.zip which is 600 Mb but this should have been 900 Mb is there any way to resume this one using wget, I am on 12.04

Comment: Useful link: [Which download manager is capable of 'throttle' and 'pause & resume' a running instance of download from a script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/273000/which-download-manager-is-capable-of-throttle-and-pause-resume-a-running-i?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This ain't really a Ubuntu specific question.

Manual:http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-resume-download-33

However you should check the that your files got the correct checksums when finished.

Just a snippet from the manual:

Continue getting a partially-downloaded file. This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program. For instance:

```
      wget -c ftp://sunsite.doc.ic.ac.uk/ls-lR.Z
```

So for your case try:

`wget -c http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opsi/opsi/4.0.3/opsi4.0.3-2-servervm.zip`