# How can I throttle my browser downloads?

Tags: downloads

So this household is very digital. I'm the biggest user as I regularly download multi-Gig OS *.iso's.  What I would like is a means by which I can throttle these so as to be kind to my housemates. Also, this will keep them from unplugging the network gateway. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can limit Download/Upload bandwidth?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/273000/367990 - and if you use `curl` or `wget` also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39218/103151

Comment: I'd recommend using torrents for .iso files; not only does it automatically checksum each piece of the file, but most torrent programs have bandwidth limiting options.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is not clear as you didn't specify how you are downloading these files. As others mention in the comments:

- Most torrent clients support bandwidth limiting.
- Command line tools has too (`wget`, `curl`, `youtube-dl`...)

For web browsers it is nice to look for a download manager like `jdownloader`. Personally, I prefer [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) plug for Firefox.