# How to enable RPC in aria2c download manager?

Tags: download-manager

I want to enable RPC in `aria2c` download manager, so that I can pause and resume downloads from command line. When I run

```
aria2c --rpc-listen-port=6800 http://torrage.com/torrent/9C76DCCEB643D27D6ADC9253C713407D5F2AE3AF.torrent
```

an error displays...

```
unrecognized option '--rpc-listen-port=6800'
Exception: [OptionParser.cc:149] Failed to parse command-line options.

Usage: aria2c [OPTIONS] [URI | MAGNET | TORRENT_FILE | METALINK_FILE]...

Printing options tagged with '#help'.

See -h option to know other command-line options(#basic, #advanced, #http, #https, #ftp, #metalink, #bittorrent, #cookie, #hook, #file, #xml-rpc, #experimental, #help, #all).
Options:
 -h, --help[=TAG|KEYWORD]     Print usage and exit.
                              The help messages are classified with tags. A tag
                              starts with "#". For example, type "--help=#http"
                              to get the usage for the options tagged with
                              "#http". If non-tag word is given, print the usage
                              for the options whose name includes that word.
                              Possible Values: #basic, #advanced, #http, #https, #ftp, >#metalink, #bittorrent, #cookie, #hook, #file, #xml-rpc, #experimental, #help, #all
                              Default: #basic
                              Tags: #basic,#help

Refer to man page for more information.
```

What's wrong?

Refer: http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `aria` says *unrecognized option* your `aria` maybe too old and doesn't support **JSON-RPC** or RPC at all. See man page by typing `man aria2c` and search for *rpc*. In some old version *xml RPC* is available, but advance features such as *pause & resume* *adding file* will not available.
 Try `aria2c --enable-xml-rpc=true` for *xml rpc*. For enabled features: `aria2c -v`